# Router calls passport.serialize but never executes handler

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js, passport-local

So I'm using Node, Express, and Passport. I am logging users in and serializing the session like so:

```
      passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
  });


  // Deserializes the user session after a request has been completed.
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      new User().get(id)
      .then(function(user) {
          console.log("deserialized:" + user.name)
          done(err, user);
      })
  })


  passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
      new User().login(username, password)
      .then(function (user) {
        if (!user) //case where username (id, handle, email) is not found in database
        {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Login failed.' })
        }
        return done(null, user)
      })
      .fail(function (err) {
        return done(err)
      })
    }))
```

This all works, but then ALL of my subsequent route handlers invoke passport.serializeUser/passport.deserializeUser but never execute themselves.

So:

```
  router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    console.log("Logging user out")
    req.logout(); //.logout is a passport method attached to every req object
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

doesn't ever console.log or actually call logout().

What the bleep is going on??

Comment: You're not handling possible errors thrown by `new User().get(id)`. Also, `deserializeUser()` is referencing `err`, which is undefined.

Comment: That was it. Frickin 30 seconds after I posted this I saw that. Removing the reference error fixed everything haha

Comment: Code blindness, happens to the best of us ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referencing an 'err' in done where there was no error being passed from the callback

This fixed it:

```
  // Deserializes the user session after a request has been completed.
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      new User().get(id)
      .then(function(user) {
          console.log("deserialized:" + user.alias)
          done(null, user);
      })
      .fail(function (err) { done(err) })
  })
```